# Dynamically modify link rel="stylesheet" in head by react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a multi language web project made by React.js & typescript and want to using bootstrap 5 CSS.
The problem is I want to dynamically change bootstrap CSS link on head section depend on language (ltr or rtl).

This link in public/index.html file:

```
<head>
...
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">  
...
</head>
```

convert to this dynamically:

```
<head>
...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-mUkCBeyHPdg0tqB6JDd+65Gpw5h/l8DKcCTV2D2UpaMMFd7Jo8A+mDAosaWgFBPl" crossorigin="anonymous">  
...
</head>
```

After changing language I want to modify CSS link for rtl or ltr.
I'm using method on rout and successfully changing HTML dir but looking to modify  with React.js & TypeScript.

Is there any solution for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using ReactHelmet.You can create a StyleSheetUrlSelector Component. Then based on your criteria, you can render whichever stylesheet you want to render.

```
import React,{ FC } from "react";
import ReactHelmet from 'react-helmet';
interface ICssSelector {
   ltr:boolean;
}

const CssSelector:FC<ICssSelector> =(props)=>{
     const {ltr} =props;
   return(
    ltr === true? 
    <ReactHelmet link={
      [{"rel": "stylesheet", type:"text/css", "href": "/style.ltr.css"}]
    }/>
    : <ReactHelmet link={
      [{"rel": "stylesheet", type:"text/css", "href": "/style.rtl.css"}]
    }/>
   );

}
export default CssSelector
```